# Dropdown Table Header hidden by table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[photo of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQCjL.jpg)

Hello, i am working in a web app about bullyng issues in school. I want to display a table with the bullyng reports. One table header is "Cursos" that is a dropdown menu with all the school courses. The problem is that a part of the dropdown menu (starting from the third option or course) is hidden by the table, but a scrollbar appears to scroll to the rest of the courses. I want all the options to appear and prefer not to use the scrollbar to scroll the courses. Any ideas (i am new to programming so i am not very experienced with css so sorry if this is a noob question :)) 
(At the top i added a photo of the problem)
Here is my html:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Reportes de Victimas
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
<h1 class="display-3">Reportes de Víctimas</h1>
    <form action="/" method="post">
        <table class="table table-striped" id="myTableVict">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Escuela</th>
                <th>

                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" id="botoncin" id="dropdown-button">Curso
                      <span class="caret"></span></button>
                      <div class="dropdown-content"  id="divo">
                        <a href="#">Todos</a>
                        {% for hechito in hechitos %}
                        <a href="#">{{ hechito.curso }}</a>
                        {% endfor %}

                  </div>
                </th>
                <th>Descripción del hecho</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
<!--for is to loop in each row of the table of the selected database,you have to use { always with a space at left and right  and stock.nam the . because it is like opening a dict and chosing the column name -->

    {% for hecho in hechos %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ hecho.escuela }}</td>
                    <td>{{ hecho.curso }}</td>
                    <td>{{ hecho.hecho }}</td>

                </tr>
            {% endfor %}

        </tbody>
    </table>
    </form>
    <script>
              var table = document.getElementById("myTableVict");
              var inputs = table.getElementsByTagName("a");
          //    var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
              var rows = table.tBodies[0].rows

              for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {

                var input = inputs[i];

                input.addEventListener("click", function () {
                  var selectedCourse = this.textContent.trim();

                //  alert(selectedCourse);
                  for (row of rows) {

                    let td = row.getElementsByTagName('td')[1]
                    if (!td) { continue }
                    let course = td.textContent.trim()
                    if (course === selectedCourse || selectedCourse == "Todos") {

                      row.style.removeProperty('display')
                    } else {
                      row.style.setProperty('display', 'none')
                    }
                    }
                });
              }

    </script>

{% endblock %}
```

CSS:

```
/* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn, #naco {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #3e8e41;}
/* boton 2 */
.button1 {
  background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
}
```

Comment: It seems to be hidden by the container instead of table. Provide your css as well?

Comment: edit: css added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is, the dropdown is actually rendered under the scrollable container. As long as the container has the limited height, the dropdown should be cut off. So the solution is to append the dropdown underneath body element using JQuery. Please add this JQuery code.

```js
$(function() {
            var dropdownMenu;
            var dropdownButton;
            $('#dropdown-button').hover(function(e) {
            if (dropdownMenu) return;
              dropdownMenu = $(e.target).siblings('.dropdown-content');
      dropdownButton = $(e.target);
                // detach it and append it to the body
                $('body').append(dropdownMenu.detach());
 
                // grab the new offset position
                var eOffset = $(e.target).offset();
 
                // make sure to place it where it would normally go (this could be improved)
                dropdownMenu.css({
                    'display': 'block',
                        'top': eOffset.top + $(e.target).outerHeight(),
                        'left': eOffset.left
                });
            }, function(e) {
              var children = dropdownMenu.find(e.relatedTarget);
              if (children.length === 0) {
                  $(e.target).parent().append(dropdownMenu.detach());
                  dropdownMenu.hide();
                  dropdownMenu = null;
                  dropdownButton = null;
              }
            });
            
            $('.dropdown-content').mouseleave(function(e) {
             if (e.relatedTarget.id !== 'dropdown-button') {
                 dropdownButton.parent().append(dropdownMenu.detach());
                    dropdownMenu.hide();
                    dropdownMenu = null;
                    dropdownButton = null;
                }
            });
          });
```

Comment: It doesnt seem to work :( Note that i have 2 classes one is .dropdown (that includes the dropdown and the button) and the other is .dropdown-content (that just includes the content) Maybe that is the error?
Another thing: In line 3 you use find('.dropdown-menu'); But i don't have a class named .dropdown-menu,
And on the comment of dropdownMenu.css({ you say "Make sure to place it where it should go" But where exactly does it go? In my .css file? (sorry i am new to coding)
Thanks

Comment: @deloco `dropdown-menu` is a standard classname for bootstrap dropdown content. But if you need to use `.dropdown-content`, yes please update it `dropdownMenu = $(e.target).find('.dropdown-content');` at line 3. And `dropdownMenu.css({` is used to add CSS programmatically. It does not go to anywhere. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Doesn't work, tried changing the "body" in line 5 to "tbody" but doesnt work either.

Comment: @deloco it should be "body", not "tbody". Ok, I noticed you customized the dropdown in your own way, so my solution did not work. I updated my answer based on your example. Please check.

Comment: Nope, not fixed. The html extends other html that is "layout.html" that has this in its <head>: <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script> to support jquery that i think it is ok. But the code doesnt solve the problem

Comment: @deloco please send me whole codebase so that I can fix it and send it back to you

Comment: https://pastebin.com/kpndxRYs
hi, thanks you are very kind. not sure if this is the way you wanted me to send it to you

Comment: @deloco checked your codebase. Updated the answer and confirmed it works for your codebase. please test it on your end

Comment: IT WORKS! Thanks for your time trying to help me, you are awesome thanks :)
The only problem is that the menu does not close when i select a course, instead it closes when i move the mouse away but i don't know if that can be fixed

Answer (score 1):

Can you check your code at this please:-

```
<thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Escuela</th>
            <th>

            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" id="botoncin" id="dropdown-button">Curso
                  <span class="caret"></span></button>
                  <div class="dropdown-content"  id="divo">
                    <a href="#">Todos</a>
                    {% for hechito in hechitos %}
                    <a href="#">{{ hechito.curso }}</a>
                    {% endfor %}

              </div>
            </th>
            <th>Descripción del hecho</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
```

in this code your div:-

```
<div class="dropdown">
```

you didn't complete this  so that's why showing issue.
just complete it by `</div>` then will work